# deleteCharAt doesn't delete in StringBuffer

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I have 4 different stringbuffers named `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. They each containts same values `0123456789` . I have a String named `compguess` which always contains 4 digit numbers like "2912". I have a String named `result` and this string may contain values `+`, `-`, `null` or `+` and `-` signs together like `++--` or `++-`. This result string may contain max 4 values.

What I am trying to do is to drop the char from matching StringBuffer (2912=abcd) if result string contain only "-" values like "-","--","---" or "----".  But my code sometimes drops and sometimes doesn't (even the result contains only "-"). What am I doing wrong?

Here is the complete code:

```
public Randomnumber(){
    sb = new StringBuffer("123456789");
    sb2 = new StringBuffer("0123456789");
    sb3 = new StringBuffer("0123456789");
    a = new StringBuffer("123456789");
    b = new StringBuffer("0123456789");
    c = new StringBuffer("0123456789");
    d = new StringBuffer("0123456789");
    trys =0;
    usernumber="";
    x=0;
}

public String getNewrandomnumber() {
    return mynewnumber;
}
public void setusernumber(String number) {
    usernumber = number;
}
public String create4digitrandom(StringBuffer sb) {
    Random rnd = new Random();

    mysayi2 ="";
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){           
        random = rnd.nextInt(sb.length());
        mysayi2 += Character.toString(sb.charAt(random));
        sb.deleteCharAt(random);
    }       
    String str = String.valueOf(mysayi2);
    return str;
}
public String create2digitrandom(StringBuffer sb) {
    mysayi2 ="";
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        if(i<1){                
            mysayi2 += Character.toString(sb.charAt(0));
            sb.deleteCharAt(0);
        }else{
            mysayi2 += "0";
        }
    }       
    String str = String.valueOf(mysayi2);
    return str;
}
public void create3digitrandom() {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    mysayi3 ="";
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        if(i<1){                
            random = 1+rnd.nextInt(9);
            mysayi3 += Character.toString(sb2.charAt(random));
            sb2.deleteCharAt(random);
        }else{
            random = rnd.nextInt(10-i);
            mysayi3 += Character.toString(sb2.charAt(random));
            sb2.deleteCharAt(random);
        }           
        if(random2 > 1){
            mysayi3 += Character.toString(sb2.charAt(random));
        }
    }   
    random = rnd.nextInt(3);
    mysayi3 += Character.toString(mysayi3.charAt(random));
    computernumber = String.valueOf(mysayi3);
}
public String sayisalla() {
    if(trys<2){
        mysayi4=create4digitrandom(sb);
    }else if(trys>1 && trys<3){
        mysayi4=create2digitrandom(sb);
    }else{
        mysayi4=computerthink2();
    }
    trys++;
    computerresult = mysayi4+" "+comparenumbers(mysayi4,usernumber,0);  
    return computerresult;
}
public String comparenumbers(String number,String computernumber, int who) {
    result ="";
    fakecomputernumber = computernumber;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        if(number.charAt(i)==fakecomputernumber.charAt(i)){
            result += "+";
            char[] myNameChars = fakecomputernumber.toCharArray();
            myNameChars[i] = 'x';
            fakecomputernumber = String.valueOf(myNameChars);
            char[] myNameChars2 = number.toCharArray();
            myNameChars2[i] = 'y';
            number = String.valueOf(myNameChars2);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        if(number.charAt(i)!=fakecomputernumber.charAt(i)&&fakecomputernumber.indexOf(number.charAt(i))!=-1){
            result += "-";
            char[] myNameChars = fakecomputernumber.toCharArray();
            myNameChars[fakecomputernumber.indexOf(number.charAt(i))] = 'x';  
            fakecomputernumber = String.valueOf(myNameChars);
            char[] myNameChars2 = number.toCharArray();
            myNameChars2[i] = 'y';
            number = String.valueOf(myNameChars2);
        }
    }
    if(result ==""){
        result += "miss";
    }else if(result =="++++"){
        result = "Congratz you won!!!";
    }
    if(who ==0){
        computerthink(number,fakecomputernumber,result);
    }
    return result;
}
public void computerthink(String compguess, String mynumber,String result) {
    for(int i =0;i<4;i++){
        remainingnumbers += Character.toString(sb3.charAt(i));
    }   
    if(result ==""){ 
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            if(remainingnumbers.indexOf(compguess.charAt(i))!=-1){
                sb3.deleteCharAt(remainingnumbers.indexOf(compguess.charAt(i)));                    
            }
            if(i==0){
                a.deleteCharAt(a.indexOf(Character.toString(compguess.charAt(i))));
            }else if(i==1){
                b.deleteCharAt(b.indexOf(Character.toString(compguess.charAt(i))));
            }else if(i==2){
                c.deleteCharAt(c.indexOf(Character.toString(compguess.charAt(i))));
            }else if(i==3){
                d.deleteCharAt(d.indexOf(Character.toString(compguess.charAt(i))));
            }               
        }
    }else if(result !="++++" && result.length()==4){
        lengthofremaining = remainingnumbers.length();
        for(int i =0;i<lengthofremaining;i++){
            if(compguess.indexOf(remainingnumbers.charAt(i))!=-1){
                sb3.deleteCharAt(i-x);      
                x++;
            }
        }
    }else if(result =="++++"){
        result = "You lost loser!!!";
    }else if(result.indexOf("+")==-1 && result.indexOf("-")!=-1){
        for(int i =0;i<4;i++){
            if(i==0){
                if(a.indexOf(Character.toString(compguess.charAt(i))) !=-1){
                    a.deleteCharAt(a.indexOf(Character.toString(compguess.charAt(i))));
                }                   
            }else if(i==1){
                if(b.indexOf(Character.toString(compguess.charAt(i))) !=-1){
                    b.deleteCharAt(b.indexOf(Character.toString(compguess.charAt(i))));
                }
            }else if(i==2){
                if(c.indexOf(Character.toString(compguess.charAt(i))) !=-1){
                    c.deleteCharAt(c.indexOf(Character.toString(compguess.charAt(i))));
                }
            }else if(i==3){
                if(d.indexOf(Character.toString(compguess.charAt(i))) !=-1){
                    d.deleteCharAt(d.indexOf(Character.toString(compguess.charAt(i))));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public String computerthink2() {
    generatednumber ="";
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        Random rnd2 = new Random();
        if(i==0){
            randombetter = rnd2.nextInt(a.length());
            generatednumber += a.charAt(randombetter);
        }else if(i==1){
            randombetter = rnd2.nextInt(b.length());
            generatednumber += b.charAt(randombetter);
        }else if(i==2){
            randombetter = rnd2.nextInt(c.length());
            generatednumber += c.charAt(randombetter);
        }else if(i==3){
            randombetter = rnd2.nextInt(d.length());
            generatednumber += d.charAt(randombetter);
        }       
    }
    return generatednumber;
}
public String returnmynumber() {
    return computernumber;
}
}
```

here is the relevant part of my code;

```
}else if(result.indexOf("+")==-1 && result.indexOf("-")!=-1){
        for(int i =0;i<4;i++){
            if(i==0){
                if(a.indexOf(Character.toString(compguess.charAt(i))) !=-1){
                    a.deleteCharAt(a.indexOf(Character.toString(compguess.charAt(i))));
                }                   
            }else if(i==1){
                if(b.indexOf(Character.toString(compguess.charAt(i))) !=-1){
                    b.deleteCharAt(b.indexOf(Character.toString(compguess.charAt(i))));
                }
            }else if(i==2){
                if(c.indexOf(Character.toString(compguess.charAt(i))) !=-1){
                    c.deleteCharAt(c.indexOf(Character.toString(compguess.charAt(i))));
                }
            }else if(i==3){
                if(d.indexOf(Character.toString(compguess.charAt(i))) !=-1){
                    d.deleteCharAt(d.indexOf(Character.toString(compguess.charAt(i))));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Output screenshot;[game screen](http://hycome.com/game.jpg)

```
//This is the main java file which calls the class(randomnumber) i posted here


newrandomnumber = new Randomnumber(); //i define the class

newrandomnumber.create3digitrandom();
/* call create3digitrandom function in randomnumber class to create 4 digit number
   (but has 3 different numbers), this number will be computer's number
   which player will try to guess */

result3 =newrandomnumber.returnmynumber();
// added this function for now to see what computer created for itself
// it wont be in the full program

if (extras != null) {
            String mynumber = extras.getString("mynumber");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mynumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            newrandomnumber.setusernumber(mynumber);
        }   

/* The code above takes my number from previous intent to be used
   in this main class and sets my number at randomnumber class to
   be used for comparison later */


/* Below is the onclick event codes in the main java file which 
   will call randomnumber class again and do some operations like
   comparing numbers and printing in results in textview */

EditText randomnumber=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

String mynumber2 = randomnumber.getText().toString();   

result = mynumber2+" "+newrandomnumber.comparenumbers(mynumber2,newrandomnumber.returnmynumber(),1);
/* This calls comparenumbers function and send them the number I 
   wrote in editext field to compare with computer's number which
   is "newrandomnumber.returnmynumber()" and 1 means that comparison
   is for human, if it is 0 function do some extra work in it as it
   can be seen in my posted code to make better guesses next time like
   as I mention before dropping some numbers from stringbuffers which
   each stringbuffer shows a decimal. Rest of them are just printing
   results in main class. */

builder.append(result).append(rastgele+"\n");
text.setText(result3+"\n"+builder); 
result2 = newrandomnumber.sayisalla();
builder2.append(rastgele2).append(result2+"\n");
text2.setText(builder2);

/* Also I added a small function to see the changes in "a" stringbuffer,
   as you can see from the screenshot, left side is the computers guesses
   and right side is mine. Numbers like 123456789 near left side numbers
   shows stringbuffer a's content and even though there are only "-" signs
   at some computer guesses it still uses same numbers at the same decimal
   column at next guesses */
```

Comment: Perhaps by the time you get there, the relevant character has already been deleted in a previous round? You are not showing all the code and we don't know if this is running in a loop and what's happening to the buffers. As an aside, your can drop the `for` and the `if` inside it and just have the four internal `if` statement with the proper number instead of `i`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic ; i wrote a code to print stringbuffer a to see if it is droping, and no it is not :(

Comment: If you don't show the rest of your code - all the relevant part, which means all the parts that change any of the variables we see in this code, and all the parts that change any of the variables in that code as well - we won't be able to help you. We can't guess what you are doing.

Comment: @RealSkeptic ; posted all of my code above

Comment: You are comparing strings using `==` in there. And doing lots of stuff that depends on variables that are not shown in this code. Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link!), including a main method that demonstrates your problem, and show us the resulting output and what you expected. I cannot answer the question in its current state.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, hi mate i posted a screenshot of gamescreen and my main java class which calls this class to do operations

Comment: Ug. += on Strings in a loop? new Random in a loop? .append(foo + "\n") in a StringBuffer? If you want a mutable String work with a StringBuilder and then finalize it when you are done. And you really don't need to create new Randoms all over the place. I'd strongly suggest running pmd against this code. Some of it is... painful. And those String Buffers? Why not just an array of ints? For that matter, they are simple to calculate - don't need them at all.

Comment: @MichaelT , ok i will move new randoms to contructor but using += in loops is necessary for me as i am comparing numbers and returning a string according to that comparison and thats why i didnt use int array as it is fixed size however stringbuffer isnt. I will install pmd plugin, thanks

Comment: @Faruk the += for a String is almost always the completely wrong answer for how to do string concatenation. It creates a StringBuilder with the original string. It calls append. It calls toString and assigns that back to the value. Then the StringBuilder is left with 0 references. Then you do it again, and again, and again. Create a StringBuilder outside of the loop and append to that. When done with the loop, then call toString on it. You'll save a few objects. Might not be critical for such a small program, but I've seen bad habits build megabyte long strings, one character at a time with +=

Comment: When you get this all working correctly, I'd strongly suggest posting it to CodeReview.SE so that people can work help point out these small things that aren't that small and you can understand all the minor gotchas and ways to implement what you are working on better.